# Apply a protected sheet macro to all sheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that opens automatically and applies a special sheet protection which allows for grouping and some editing for a specific sheet, Program Data. The macro I have is this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  With Worksheets("Program Data")
   .EnableOutlining = True
   .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True,    
    AllowInsertingRows:=True
  End With
End Sub
```

Right now this runs as soon as you open the file, but it only applies to Program Data. I don't know how to change the with statement to accommodate the entire workbook without naming the sheets one-by-one. But there are very many sheets, so that's not a good option. How do I do apply this for all sheets in the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a `For` loop that targets all the sheets. Basically...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
    .EnableOutlining = True
    .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True,    
    AllowInsertingRows:=True
    End With
  Next WS
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 10):

You can loop through the worksheet objects like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .EnableOutlining = True
            .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
            AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
    With Worksheets(i)
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True,  AllowFormattingColumns:=True,     AllowInsertingRows:=True
    End With
Next
```